# Phantom activity on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, shared-hosting

This is probably just my total lack of MySQL expertise, but is it typical to see lots of phantom activity on a MySQL instance via phpMyAdmin?

I have a shared hosting plan through Lithium, and when I log in through the phpMyAdmin console and click on the 'Status' tab, it's showing crazy high numbers for queries. Within an hour of activating my account I had > 1 million queries. At first I thought this was them setting things up, but the number is climbing constantly, averaging > 170/second.

I've got a support ticket in with Lithium, but I thought I'd ask here if this were a MySQL/shared host thing, because I had the same thing happen with a shared hosting plan through Joyent.

Comment: First Guess: They're showing activity for the entire system. Second Guess: Somebody's trying to hack your db.

Comment: Yeah, the support ticket came back and he said that it's for the whole server. Anyone have any idea how to get stats for just your databases?

Answer (score 1):

I have shared hosting with the same provider and I see the same thing (currently showing 178 queries per second). I would imagine that jnpcl is correct and the activity shown is for all accounts on the same MySQL server as you.

Edit:

*Anyone have any idea how to get stats for just your databases?*

[This ticket](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=16524) suggests it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. But then again, since mysql was acquired I notice they have a commercial edition, so maybe stuff like that will he implemented but not in the free edition.